# Plotting a square frame in some region of the graph (gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 2D graph at gnuplot. The range of the current graph is

```
xrange [x1:x2]
yrange [y1:y2]
```

I want to draw a square frame from a to b in the x-axis and from c to d in the y-axis.
In this case x1 < a,b < x2 and y1 < c,d < y2. This is because I will plot another graph with

```
xrange [a:b]
yrange [c:d]
```

But I want to somehow enphasize the "zoom" region in the first graph.

I searched on the internet, but had no sucess. You guys have any idea or reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its only to draw a frame, i.e. a border, you can use `set object rectangle`:

```
set xrange [x1:x2]
set yrange [y1:y2]
set object rectangle from a,c to b,d

plot "data.txt"
```

Note, that an object behaves like a lable, i.e. you can change the layer with the keywords `front`, `back` and `behind`. And it is plotted only together with a following `plot` command.